# memoir: Set chapter title below page number entry TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm trying to create a table of contents in which the chapter number and page number are on one line, and a short summary of the chapter are in a paragraph below. Something like this:

```
Chapter 1 .................... 1
    In which the main character
    does this and that.
Chapter 2 .................... 23
    In which the main character
    continues  to  do  this and
    that.
Chapter 3 .................... 38
    In which the main character
    encounters an obstacle.
```

The summary text (i.e. "In which...") has been used as the chapter title throughout the document (i.e. `\chapter{In which...}`).
How can I accomplish this effect? I'm using the `memoir` class.

Comment: What you are looking for is chapter precis. Have a look at section 6.5.3 of the memoir manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memoir provide three commands for that. `\chapterprecis{text}` print `text` in the place where is written and in the toc, `\chapterprecishere{text}` print `text` only in the place where is written and `\chapterprecistoc{text}` print `text` only in toc. An example of those three is

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapterprecis{In which the main character does this and that.}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapterprecishere{In which the main character continues  to  do  this and}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapterprecistoc{In which the main character encounters an obstacle.}
\end{document}
```

[image]